# Realm-iOS: Model object becomes nil when it's added to realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm

It's an RSS reader app. I instantiate my model object, call setupFavIcon() on it to download favIcon which is nil when creating an object. Then I add each object to realm. But when the icon is actually fetched, self is nil, so I can't update app's UI. I don't understand why self becomes nil.

```
class Article: Object {
  dynamic var source = ""
  dynamic var title = ""
  dynamic var link = ""
  dynamic var pubDate = Date()
  dynamic var favIcon: Data?

  dynamic var favIconDidLoad: (() -> ())?

  func setupFavIcon(_ source: String) {
    DownloadManager.sharedInstance.downloadFavIcon(source) { [weak self] icon in
      if let icon = icon {
        self?.favIcon = icon
        self?.favIconDidLoad?()
      }
    }
  }

  override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "link"
  }

  override class func ignoredProperties() -> [String] {
    return ["favIconDidLoad"]
  }
}
```

Closure favIconDidLoad is defined in my TableViewCell class and invoked when favIcon is downloaded.

```
  fileprivate func setupFavIcon(_ article: Article) {
    if let favicon = article.favIcon {
      setFavIcon(favicon)
    } else {
      article.favIconDidLoad = { [weak self] in
        self?.setFavIcon(article.favIcon)
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep strong reference to your Article objects. When you load them from realm you need keep them in array. if you operate on results from realm they are released when method TableViewCell setupFavIcon ends.

Comment: Yes, my app was using data directly from the realm. Now I store objects in separate array and only getting data from realm only when there's no internet connection. Now, favIcons are displayed properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You use `weak` reference to `self` in `downloadFavIcon` closure that most likely is called asynchronously, so your objects could be already deallocated. You need to use strong reference in closure or keep strong references to your objects somewhere.

Also note: if object is added to Realm, all changes to an object (addition, modification and deletion) must be done within a write transaction.